# How can I keep permissions on original files when restoring backups with Duplicity?

Tags: backup, restore, duplicity

**When restoring files backed up by Duplicity, is there a way to keep the original permissions on the files extracted?** I need to run the restore as root, and it seems that makes all the files restored owned by root.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, consider using rsync to do both, the backup and the restore.  It takes care of keeping the files ownership and properties correctly while also has a number of features like delta-backups.  (as commented, in order to preserve the ownership you will have to run whatever backup tool you choose as root)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicity can and does restore permissions and owner of your files/folders as they were before the backup. To restore the owner two prerequisites have to be met:

1. The restore command has to be run as root, as only root is allowed to `chown`.
2. A user named the same needs to exist on the target machine.

During the restore process the files and folders will be owned by root, but once it finishes Duplicity will set the owner to reflect the original if the above demands are met.

..ede/duply.net